# What do the github color bars mean in github?

Tags: github

What do the various color bars stand for in github?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try clicking on them and you'll see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colors represent the different languages used inside of the project. I believe if you click on the colors the text will change and tell you exactly what languages are used and what percentage of the total project is written in each language.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think to click on the bar itself because it wasn't a [percieved affordance] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance) like the buttons for Clone or Download, New pull request, etc were.